# Wood flooring options for dogs, finish options

Tags: hardwood-floor

I am very new to flooring and have a new project that needs to be undertaken within the next few months.

To outline, we have two dogs that spend the day in the area we are looking to lay the new floor. We have been looking at bamboo flooring which we believe is the best for pets due to the fact they will not slip on it.

However, aside from it being possibly too pricey, we are not able to find the ideal colour so have been exploring alternative hard wood floors and then laying down a matt resin to help primarily with sealing against urine and water (from their bowl).

So the main concerns are:

- Is it possible to lay a resin coat down over a wooden floor?
- Is a resin coat generally OK for dogs with regards them slipping on it as well as being relatively urine resistant?
- Are there any alternatives we could possibly look at? We are not keen on vinyl or laminate.

Thanks in advance.

Dave

Comment: You should *not* put the dogs' water bowl directly on the floor. Put a thick terry cloth bathmat under the bowl so that you don't have a puddle under and around the bowl.

Comment: Thanks Jim. Do you have any thoughts on the three points raised at the end of my question?

Comment: Your term "resin" presumably means what I would call varnish. Nowadays this would be polyurethane. This would be applied to wood plank flooring finished in place. This ought to seal the joints between the planks against the occasional urine accident. Most modern wood floors are prefinished and so the joints are not sealed. This would allow urine to soak into the joints.

Comment: We have dogs in our house (2100 sq ft).  We redid all the floors in our 50-year-old house in ceramic (porcelain) tile--18 inch squares called "Continental Slate" colour "English grey". The tiles are adhered to the concrete slab with so called "thinset mortar" installed by a guy from Huddersfield. The grout lines are sealed with a polymeric sealer, but still react to the dogs' occasional urine accident. The tiles have a roughened surface which gives the dogs some purchase, but we discourage the dogs from  running in the house.

Comment: What is the construction of your "subfloor"? Presumably in Manchester UK it would be wood--probably planking or plywood, over joists. The traditional finish floor for that here in the US would be hardwood planks, usually oak, but people have gotten away from that here due to the cost. What is the usual floor in Manchester?

Comment: Hardwood and water are just not a good combination. Sooner or later, urine or water from the bowl will get into the cracks between the boards and swell the edges of the wood.  There is no foolproof way to seal it because wood expands and contracts with the seasons.  Put the water bowel inside a large rubber "tray" with a lip around the edge.  Any water that gets held against the floor (wet towel, water wicking under a waterproof pad, etc.), will have a long time to affect the floor.  Your best bet is wall to wall sheet vinyl, even if it just sits on top of your flooring.  Dogs aren't offended.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. Jim, the floorboards sit on joists with about a half a foot gap, then the ceiling from the basement.

We weren't thinking of varnish as such, more of a resin layer like this: http://i937.photobucket.com/albums/ad220/khani123123/297a366b.jpg which I believe should offer protection against urine/water?